# Как изменить цвет элемента TimePicker для диалогового окна

Tags: java, android, android-dialog, datetimepicker

У меня есть класс 
TimePickerDialog

```java
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Пробовал изменять цвет через установку стиля. Применял стиль приложения, но все равно максимум, чего добился, это изменение цвета окна:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5seva.png

Буду  весьма признателен, если поможете найти решение!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цвет у `TimePicker` можно поменять через стили таким образом:

```
<style name="TimePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

сюда можно добавить и другие параметры такие как `backGround` и тому подобное. Дальше в активности/диалоге вы пишете так:

```
TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(mContext, R.style.TimePickerTheme, fromListener, hour, min, false);
```

Я использовал этот метод и все заработало нормально, надеюсь и у вас все получится.